# ActionButton icons not getting displayed in ActionOverFlow area of Kivy ActionBar

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have setup some buttons in an action bar and used images as icons. The buttons get displayed when the app window is maximized but they are not visible in the overflow area when the app window is resized (made small). I see only blank black boxes. Can you please help?

Kivy Code:

```
<SivaStatusScreen>:
    name: 'status_screen'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        id: status_layout
        size_hint: 1, 1
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            id: actionbar_layout
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            ActionBar:
                id: status_actionbar
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                background_image: ''
                background_color: 195/255, 60/255, 35/255, 1
                ActionView:
                    use_separator: True
                    ActionPrevious:
                        title: 'S.I.V.A'
                        with_previous: False
                    ActionOverflow:
                    ActionButton:
                        important: True
                        icon: 'images/communication-96.png'
                    ActionButton:
                        important: True
                        icon: 'images/key-96.png'
                    ActionButton:
                        important: True
                        icon: 'images/services-96.png'
                    ActionButton:
                        important: True
                        icon: 'images/shutdown-96.png'
        BoxLayout:
            id: status_display
            size_hint: 1, 0.9
    AnchorLayout:
        id: status_add
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        ImageButton:
            id: status_addbtn
            source: {'normal': 'images/plus-96.png', 'down': 'images/plusblue-96.png'} [self.state]
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
```

The button icons are visible when the window is maximized. The button icons are not visible in the action overflow area when the window is minimized. However, text labels of buttons and text buttons do get displayed properly. Could it be that the size of the drop down is restricting the icons from getting displayed?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes in the Python side (defined some new custom classes):

```
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


class CustomActionButton(ImageButton, ActionItem):
    pass
```

Some changes in the Kivy side:

```
<CustomActionButton>:
    size_hint_x: 0.05
    size_hint_min_x: 48
```

Setting the width of the widget along the x-axis and minimum pixel width for the icons did the trick. The buttons are now working as per expectation.